# Bronze Tag Badge Requirement

Tags: support, badges, tag-badges

I had a question about the requirements for winning the bronze tag badge:

> You must have a total score of 100 in at least 20 non-community wiki answers to achieve this badge.

Does this mean I can take at least 20 or more answers to eventually get a 100 total answer score?  Or do I need to get the total 100 answer score in a certain finite amount of answers.

Comment: [Please refer this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/68395/312043)

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean?

Comment: See [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67397/list-of-all-badges-with-full-descriptions#68395).

Answer (score 1):

You need to answer for the 20 or more questions on the specific tag and the total answer vote count on the tag should be greater than or equal to 100.

This restriction is not getting the tag badge for simply answering very few questions.

Comment: So I must get a total of at least 100 answer points in at least 20 or more questions, all on the same tag?  What if a question has the same tag, but also another tag on it?

Comment: For an example: If you were answered 20 questions, each answers received 5 upvotes and all the 20 questions have the same five tags. Then you will receive the 5 bronze tag medal for those 5 tags.

Comment: Should be score (upvotes &minus; downvotes), not vote count.